# Is it permissible in islam to scrape data of any website although, the website owner doesn't allow it?

Tags: halal-haram, fatwa, halal-certification

I was working at a company. Their main product is a browser extension that scrapes data of any website and they don't care about the website owner's permission. Even some websites put Recaptcha on every page but they can pass it using various techniques.

Is it halal?

They claim that if it is haram then data entry is also haram. but I am not convinced at their logic.

Here is an example of this kind of tool:

https://webscraper.io/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is 'web scraping' permitted in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12929/is-web-scraping-permitted-in-islam)

Comment: I saw that. But there are mixed opinion out there

Comment: https://islamqa.org/hanafi/askimam/83793 Check it out!